# Is there a name for the experience/ phenomenon of dreaming while being partially awake?

Tags: consciousness, dreams

Is there a name for the experience/ phenomenon of dreaming while being partially awake, being able to decide to wake up when dreaming, having control of the self character in a dream, etc?

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to remove a lot of the details of your personal experiences - they might be quite interesting but also makes your question a bit too much a personal question which is not on-topic here.

Comment: @BryanKrause I posted a commentary in the other post. Probably several features explained in depth were relevant. I think your answer fits well the first experience I described. I dont think it's the same for the second experience I described which is the one the question is about.

Comment: It seems to me that you could be describing the alpha-theta state.

Answer (score 1):

A dream where you are aware you are dreaming is called a [lucid dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream) (see also La Berge et al 1981). Lucid dreams can have varying level of control; in La Berge et al 1981 subjects were able to report by eye movements and fist clenches when they were lucid dreaming, and were verified to be in REM sleep when this occurred.

Being aware of your outside surroundings, on the other hand, is called being awake and is not the same as dreaming but could be considered [daydreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daydream).

Some people report that they often have lucid dreams, and lucid dreaming is more common in some patient populations like narcoleptics (Dodet et al 2015).

There are methods to encourage lucid dreaming if one wants to experience them (La Berge 1980, Zadra et al 1992).

---

Dodet, P., Chavez, M., Leu-Semenescu, S., Golmard, J. L., & Arnulf, I. (2015). Lucid dreaming in narcolepsy. Sleep, 38(3), 487-497.

La Berge, S. P. (1980). Lucid dreaming as a learnable skill: A case study. Perceptual and Motor Skills, 51(3_suppl2), 1039-1042.

La Berge, S. P., Nagel, L. E., Dement, W. C., & Zarcone Jr, V. P. (1981). Lucid dreaming verified by volitional communication during REM sleep. Perceptual and motor skills, 52(3), 727-732.

Zadra, A. L., Donderi, D. C., & Pihl, R. O. (1992). Efficacy of lucid dream induction for lucid and non-lucid dreamers. Dreaming, 2(2), 85.

Comment: I voted you up, but it might not be the same . Does a lucid dream include awareness of your real life surroundings and the ability to move your real life extremities? A lucid dream is what I described in my first experience,not this one. BTW, I believe the edit you made was too radical. I probably will end up having to re-post various segments of what it was in the original post, in the commentaries or whatever. In the link , in the definition section it's mentioned awareness of anything related to the dream, but I dont see mentions about anything outside the dream in the real-life enviroment.

Comment: @Pablo See edits. Your post in its original form, or even segments of its original form, will be way too much like asking for a personal diagnosis which is not allowed here. I edited your post and provided this answer to give you some search terms to continue your further research on your own, which is all that is allowed here.